# How can I multiply matrix and vector element wise like Numpy?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have an $M \times K$ matrix $C$ and a length $K$ vector $v$.  I want to form the $M \times K$ matrix $S$ where $s_{ij} = C_{ij}/v_j$.  To do this in numpy I simply divide the two objects like this

```
  S = C/v
```

but that fails in *Mathematica*.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: `S=#/v & @@@ C;` Best regards to Mr.Wizard!

Comment: @faleichik Shouldn't that be `#/v & /@ C`?

Comment: One important thing to keep in mind when you're coming from MATLAB is that arrays in Mathematica are general $n$-dimensional tensors, while MATLAB works with matrices only.  This has a significant influence on how operations work in the two systems.  In Mathematica there is no such thing as a row vector and columns vector: a vector is a strictly 1D structure and both the product `vec.mat` and `mat.vec` work.  (You can of course have an $1\times n$ or $n\times 1$ matrix.)  Operations between $m \times k$ matrices and $m$-length vectors do work automatically, but not with $k$-length vectors.

Comment: Another advice: don't use identifiers with capital names in Mathematica to avoid conflicts with builtins and packages.  Both `C` and `K` are built-in symbols, and assigning to either of them will break the system in subtle ways (for those who wonder, yes: even assigning to `K` breaks it, I have seen examples).

Comment: @Heike yes, it definitely should. I promise to never post anything without verifying it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that Mathematica wants to match up $v$ with the *rows* of $C$. In order to get what you want, you can do:

```
S=Transpose[Transpose[C]/v]
```

Comment: Here's what it should look like :[Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wdqtr.png)

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I'll construct a $5\times3$ matrix of ones to use for illustration purposes:

```
m = ConstantArray[1,{5, 3}]
```

> [image]

We can multiply each row by the corresponding element from a vector using simple multiplication:

```
m*{1,2,3,4,5}
```

> [image]

Multiplying each column by the corresponding element from a vector is a bit more complicated.  There are several possibilities, some of which are already covered by others, but here's one I like for being conceptually simple in that it doesn't use `Transpose` or explicit iteration (`Table`, `Map`, etc...)

```
ScalingTransform[{1,2,3}][m]
```

> [image]

This could also be written using postfix notation `m // ScalingTransform[{1,2,3}]` if desired.

---

After looking at Artes's timing comparison, the `ScalingTransform` approach is quite slow, since it's constructing a large dense matrix.  We can use the same underlying idea using a specially constructed `SparseArray`, however, which is much faster:

```
m.SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> {1,2,3,4,5}]

Cc = RandomReal[{100}, {700, 900}];
v = RandomReal[{100}, {900}];

ScalingTransform[1/v][Cc]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {16.333062, Null} *)

Cc.SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1/v]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.021044, Null} *)
```

Comment: One thing I always wondered: In Mathematica, is `Transpose` an $O(1)$ operation or is it proportional to the number of elements?  (Does it actually copy stuff in memory or does it just flip a switch on how to interpret the in-memory data?)

Comment: @Szabolcs I believe `Transpose` actually copies stuff in memory, which is backed up by looking at how long it takes to transpose matrices of various (large-ish) sizes.

Comment: `DiagonalMatrix[1/v, SparseArray]` will work as well.

Answer (score 11):

Not the most efficient way but sufficiently instructive can be  for example this:

```
Cc = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 4}]
v = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {4}]
S = Table[Cc[[i, j]]/v[[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

> ```
>   {{7, 9, 6, 4}, {2, 3, 5, 8}, {6, 1, 7, 4}} 
>   {2, 2, 4, 3}
>   {{7/2, 9/2, 3/2, 4/3}, {1, 3/2, 5/4, 8/3}, {3, 1/2, 7/4, 4/3}}
> ```

This hasn't been mentioned, it's nice but not very efficient :

```
Inner[Divide, Cc, v, List]
```

Let's compare performances of various methods :

```
Cc = RandomReal[{100}, {700, 900}];
v  = RandomReal[{100}, {900}];

S1 = Table[ Cc[[i, j]] / v[[j]], {i, 1, 700}, {j, 1, 900}]; // AbsoluteTiming
S2 = Inner[Divide, Cc, v, List]; // AbsoluteTiming
S3 = #/v & /@ Cc; // AbsoluteTiming
S4 = Transpose[Transpose[Cc]/v]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.1080000, Null} 
> {0.4310000, Null}
> {0.0180000, Null} 
> {0.0260000, Null}
> ```

```
S1 == S2 == S3 == S4
```

> ```
> True
> ```

It appears the method based on `Map` is the best with respect to performance issues.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank You !  I should add that `Inner[ Times, Cc, 1/v, List]` is a bit more efficient that `Inner[Divide, Cc, v, List]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can get results roughly equally fast to sblom's double-`Transpose` approach using the generalised version of `Inner`.

```
Inner[Divide, matrix, vector, List]
```

**Timing tests**
Set up some example data:

```
ci = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {20, 3}];
cr = RandomReal[{0., 100.}, {20, 3}];
vi = {3, 2, 1};
vr = {3., 2., 1.};
```

*Division*

```
In[38]:= Do[Transpose[Transpose[ci]/vi];, {1000}] // Timing (*sblom*)

Out[38]= {0.047, Null}

In[39]:= Do[#/vi & /@ ci;, {1000}] // Timing (* faleichik/Heike in comments*)

Out[39]= {0.172, Null}

In[56]:= Do[Inner[Divide, ci, vi, List];, {1000}] // Timing (* me *)

Out[56]= {0.047, Null}

In[40]:= Do[ScalingTransform[1/vi][ci];, {1000}] // Timing (* Brett *)

Out[40]= {0.39, Null}

(* as before but for real numbers *)

In[41]:= Do[Transpose[Transpose[cr]/vr];, {1000}] // Timing  

Out[41]= {0.016, Null}

In[42]:= Do[#/vr & /@ cr;, {1000}] // Timing

Out[42]= {0.109, Null}

In[57]:= Do[Inner[Divide, cr, vr, List];, {1000}] // Timing

Out[57]= {0.031, Null}

In[43]:= Do[ScalingTransform[1/vr][cr];, {1000}] // Timing

Out[43]= {0.36, Null}
```

*Multiplication*
As an aside, because of the way `Divide` works internally, if you are dividing through by the same vector a lot, it makes some sense to create a vector that is `1./thefirstvector` and multiply through with that. The effect is more noticeable if you have integer data.

```
ivi = 1/vi;
ivr = 1./vr;


In[82]:= Do[Transpose[Transpose[ci]*ivi];, {1000}] // Timing 
Out[82]= {0.031, Null}

In[83]:= Do[#*ivi & /@ ci;, {1000}] // Timing
Out[83]= {0.125, Null}

In[84]:= Do[Inner[Times, ci, ivi, List];, {1000}] // Timing

Out[84]= {0.031, Null}


In[85]:= Do[ScalingTransform[ivi][ci];, {1000}] // Timing

Out[85]= {0.375, Null}

In[86]:= Do[Transpose[Transpose[cr]*ivr];, {1000}] // Timing

Out[86]= {0.016, Null}

In[87]:= Do[#*ivr & /@ cr;, {1000}] // Timing

Out[87]= {0.063, Null}

In[88]:= Do[Inner[Times, cr, ivr, List];, {1000}] // Timing

Out[88]= {0.031, Null}


In[89]:= Do[ScalingTransform[ivr][cr];, {1000}] // Timing

Out[89]= {0.343, Null}
```

Comment: See somewhat related question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7663695/758485

Answer (score 4):

```
m = ConstantArray[1, {5, 3}];
```

Multiply Columns

```
m * {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Multiply Rows

```
m * Threaded[{1, 2, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

[Threaded](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threaded.html) came with V 13.1