# strange timing result of LinearAlgebra`BLAS` in mathematica?

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra, undocumented

BLAS is short for "Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms". It is a famous collection of routines for doing linear algebra. I just know from [Oleksandr R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99519/4742) that mma can directly call BLAS under the context "LinearAlgebra`BLAS". I don't know why mma makes it undocumented.

Oleksandr R. provide an example of using [GER](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/da8/dger_8f.html)

$$ \mathrm{GER}: \alpha, \vec{x}, \vec{y}, \mathbf{A} : \mathbf{A} \leftarrow \alpha \vec{x} {\vec{y}}^\mathrm{T} + \mathbf{A} $$

like this

```
A = RandomReal[1., {40000000, 2}];
alpha = 1.;
x = ConstantArray[1., Length[A]];
y = {1., 2.};
LinearAlgebra`BLAS`GER[alpha, x, y, A]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

to achieve the same result of

```
Transpose[{1., 2.} + Transpose@A]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Oleksandr R.'s timing shows that BLAS approach is faster. While strangely, on my computer, I tried many times BLAS is much slower than double transpose with mma 10.3, windows system.

[image]

I also tried it on an HPC with linux version mma 10.3 installed

[image]

At this moment, it seems that maybe it is the problem of windows version 10.3. But after I tried on my friend's computer, I know it is not. Here is timing on his computer, also windows system

[image]

**So what is wrong, how to explain this?** My cpu is Intel Core i3-4500U, and 64 bit win8 system. My memory is 8GB, and there is 1.2GB for ramdisk

Comment: Try adding parentheses, e.g. `(LinearAlgebra\`BLAS\`GER[alpha, x, y, A]; // AbsoluteTiming)` to be sure you are not timing something else. Also keep in mind, as @OleksandrR mentioned, that it is not a fair comparison if you are overwriting `A`.

Comment: Does your computer have an AMD processor? How about the HPC cluster? It seems unlikely, but perhaps this could explain it.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yeah, unlikely, both are intel

Comment: @ilian Actually, I didn't see any significant different whether to add overwriting A or not. So I just omitted. And after all, this is apparently not the point. Since on my friend's computer, the code is exactly the same

Comment: @matheorem In your Linux screenshot, the timing measured for `In[1]` definitely includes generating `A` which is not correct. As for the Windows difference, I haven't been able to reproduce it. Could you perhaps include the exact CPU models and the amount of RAM for both machines? I'd also suggest setting `$HistoryLength=0` first.

Comment: @ilian You are right. I made a mistake in timing linux version. The new timing shows there is no problem on my HPC. So now, the only problem is my computer, I replaced my original timing according to your request, and add my cpu info at the end of my post.

Comment: So far it looks like an unreproducible result (unreproducible by a site user other than the OP)...

Comment: @MichaelE2 yeah, this is the strangest point, because I can reproduce it every time: )  even I reinstalled mathematica ...