# more numerically accurate inverse matrix

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, precision-and-accuracy

I encountered the following matrix

```
mat = {{2, 
   2.161209223472559` + 1.682941969615793` I}, {2.161209223472559` - 
    1.682941969615793` I, 2}}
```

and `Inverse[mat]` will give

```
{{-0.57092 - 1.06364*10^-16 I, 
  0.616939 + 0.480412 I}, {0.616939 - 0.480412 I, -0.57092 - 
   1.11022*10^-16 I}}
```

Notice there is small imaginary part and they ought to be zero. as you can see from general symbolic calculation.

```
In[494]:= Inverse[{{a, b + I c}, {b - I c, a}}]

Out[494]= {{1/(1 - b^2 - c^2), (-b - I c)/(
  1 - b^2 - c^2)}, {(-b + I c)/(1 - b^2 - c^2), 1/(1 - b^2 - c^2)}}
```

Normally, those small part won't bother. But I am doing iteration calculation right now, in each iteration step, there is inversion process and I found those small part in every step will greatly affect the result after only 30 iteration.

According to [this link](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690456/numerically-stable-inverse-of-a-2x2-matrix), inverse matrix should never be performed and they recommend linear equation solving. So for example

```
mat1={{I, -1}, {-1, -I}}
mat2={{-I, -1}, {-1, I}}
```

and we want to calculate

```
mat1.Inverse[mat].mat2
```

we could do it without inverse like this

```
mat1.LinearSolve[mat,mat2]
```

But I found this give exactly the same result as directly calculating Inverse

The way I can think of is to Chop matrix at every step, but I don't know whether it will accumulate other kind of error in the iteration process.

**So what is the correct way to deal with inverse matrix in this case?**

PS: I also found Python's numpy gives more accurate inverse than Mathematica. for example, `numpy.linalg.inv(mat)` gives imaginary part 6x10^-17, and `np.dot(np.dot(mat1,mat),mat2)` will not present imaginary part.

---

**Update**

**first**

As Karsten 7. has pointed out, `Method -> "CofactorExpansion"` will give correct result. And I think this method is actually using direct formula like the following for 2x2 matrix

$$\mathbf A^{-1}=\frac1{\det \mathbf A}\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}$$

Though `CofactorExpansion` is slower than direct `Inverse`, but for 2x2 matrix, it is acceptable efficient. But I have no idea about the numerical stability.

**Second**

The thing I don't understand right now is that even using Mathematica's ``` LinearAlgebra``Lapack ```([see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99519/4742)) still can't get the correct answer, but simple fortran coding using lapack do give the correct answer !!!!

According to `Lapack`,

> "getrf" Computes the LU factorization of a general m-by-n matrix.
>
> "getri"  Computes the inverse of an LU-factored general matrix.

so we have the following code

```
tmp = mat;
ipiv = ConstantArray[1, Length@tmp];
LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`GETRF[tmp, ipiv, info];
LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`GETRI[tmp, ipiv, info];
tmp
```

But this gives result

```
{{-0.57092 - 1.06364*10^-16 I, 
  0.616939 + 0.480412 I}, {0.616939 - 0.480412 I, -0.57092 - 
   1.11022*10^-16 I}}
```

exactly the same wrong result as direct `Inverse`!!

But I have tried fortran coding below

```
program testinversion
use lapack95
use f95_precision
implicit none
complex*16,dimension(2,2)::a
integer,dimension(2)::ipiv
integer::info
a=reshape((/(2.,0.),(2.161209223472559,-1.682941969615793),(2.161209223472559,1.682941969615793),(2.,0.)/),(/2,2/))
call zgetrf(2, 2, a, 2, ipiv, info)
if(info==0) then
call getri(a,ipiv,info)
print*,a
else
print*,"error"
endif
end program testinversion
```

Compile it with

```
ifort testinversion.f90 -mkl=sequential -lmkl_blas95_lp64 -lmkl_lapack95_lp64
```

it gives the correct result!

[image]

**What is wrong with Mathematica's LAPACK?**

---

**update2**

Solving inverse of 2x2 mat is actually equivalent to solving 
$$mat \cdot x = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{array}} \right)$$

But `LinearSolve[mat,{1,0}]` gives

```
{-0.57092 - 5.91873*10^-17 I, 0.616939 - 0.480412 I}
```

looking at the document of `LinearSolve`, I found more things:
"CofactorExpansion","DivisionFreeRowReduction","OneStepRowReduction" are actually designed for symbolic solving. For numerical solving, There are "Banded"
"Cholesky","Krylov","Multifrontal".

For this paticular simple problm, mathematica choosed a wrong method??!!

As I tested, both "Krylov" and "Multifrontal" can give correct answer.

So now, I don't know whether `Inverse` is using `LinearSolve`, but apparently, automatic method in `LinearSolve` is also bugged.

Comment: What happens if you try the computations at higher precision? In any case, `LinearSolve[]` is still preferable over `Inverse[]`.

Comment: @J.M. But why `LinearSolve[]` gives exactly the same result?

Comment: @J.M. How to set precision in `Inverse` ? there is no option

Comment: You know `SetPrecision[]`, right?

Comment: @J.M. Sorry again. I found SetPrecision does make the imaginary part smaller and smaller, but won't make it disappear. SetPrecision[mat,500] will give imaginary part (10^-521)

Comment: (1) Version 10.3 on Linux here is what I see for those products. `In[59]:= mat1.LinearSolve[mat, mat2]

Out[59]= {{-0.181014708395 + 0. I, 
  0. + 0.181014708395 I}, {0. - 0.181014708395 I, -0.181014708395 + 
   0. I}}

In[60]:= mat1.Inverse[mat].mat2

Out[60]= {{-0.181014708395 + 0. I, 
  0. + 0.181014708395 I}, {0. - 0.181014708395 I, -0.181014708395 + 
   0. I}}`. For the inverse itself, I get `In[37]:= Inverse[mat]

Out[37]= {{-0.570919803469 + 6.01693250938*10^-17 I, 
  0.61693857256 + 0.480412449271 I}, {0.61693857256 - 
   0.480412449271 I, -0.570919803469 + 5.55111512313*10^-17 I}}`.

Comment: (2) This is almost certainly BLAS and OS dependent.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You are right. The result of imaginary part is OS dependent. But that is not the whole story, see my update!

Comment: Just to be sure. You aren't calculating the `Inverse` in order to solve a linear system, are you?

Comment: @Karsten7. Yeah, I am not solving linear system, I am calculation green function

Comment: "I am not solving linear system" - in other words, you are **not** multiplying this inverse matrix with anything else, are you?

Comment: @J.M. Well, I am reconsidering whether calculating green function is solving linear system, because I have to multiply this inverse matrix with other matrix in every step. But as I said, I already tried to convert the multiplication to `LinearSolve` problem, it gives the same wrong answer.

Comment: @J.M. I think the major problem is that `Inverse` in mma doesn't gives correct result as Matlab, Maple, more importantly, Lapack in mma is not conform with MKL lapack !

Comment: "I have to multiply this inverse matrix with other matrix" - then yes, you are solving a linear system. As to why `LinearSolve[]` is acting like this for a manifestly Hermitian system, I don't yet have any ideas.

Answer (score 13):

Setting the `Method` option to `"CofactorExpansion"` results in the correct output.

```
mat = {{2, 2.161209223472559` + 1.682941969615793` I}, 
       {2.161209223472559` - 1.682941969615793` I, 2}}

Inverse[mat, Method -> "CofactorExpansion"]
```

$\ $ `{{-0.57092 + 0. I, 0.616939 + 0.480412 I}, {0.616939 - 0.480412 I, -0.57092 + 0. I}}`

---

As you want to perform iterative calculations, it might be in general a good idea to [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) `mat`.

```
Inverse[Rationalize[mat, 0]]
```

[image: out]

```
N @ %
```

$\ $ `{{-0.57092, 0.616939 + 0.480412 I}, {0.616939 - 0.480412 I, -0.57092}}`

---

One can also use [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetPrecision.html) as suggested in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102261/more-numerically-accurate-inverse-matrix/102264?noredirect=1#comment277513_102261) by [J. M.♦](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m), but needs to set it to `Infinity`.

```
Inverse[SetPrecision[mat, ∞]]
```

[image: out]

```
N @ %
```

$\ $ `{{-0.57092, 0.616939 + 0.480412 I}, {0.616939 - 0.480412 I, -0.57092}}`

Comment: Thank you. Rationalize is not suitable for me. Because I have to repeat iteration for thousands of times and rationalize is too slow. And for `Method -> "CofactorExpansion"`, it indeed works. But on what circumstances that we should use "CofactorExpansion"? How can we be sure that it will be suitable in later iteration process?Why mma doesn't automatically choose the right way?

Comment: Oh, I just read http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Invertible_matrix#/Eigen_decomposition . It seems that cofactor expansion is the same thing as the symbolic inversion formula and should be effective only for small matrix. But numerical instability is not mentioned in wikipedia

Comment: @matheorem With using `Rationalize` I didn't mean to `Rationalize` `mat` every time you use `Inverse`, but to `Rationalize` it just one. If that is possible and makes sense depends on the rest of your iteration process.

Comment: @matheorem With respect to why Mma doesn't choose `"CofactorExpansion"`, I can only cite the documentation: "For matrices with approximate real or complex numbers, the inverse is generated to the maximum possible precision given the input." "The default setting of Automatic switches among these methods depending on the matrix given." That means that the default isn't designed for your special situation, where you want to have a result with a higher precision than the input. Another reason not to use `"CofactorExpansion"` is that it is slower than `Automatic` for bigger matrices.

Comment: what does maximum possible precision mean? btw, i updated my post

Answer (score 7):

I agree the imaginary parts should be zero. I do not know why they are not zero. But this is what I found, too small to put in comment.

First, Matlab does give zero for the exact same input:

```
format long g
mat = [2, 2.161209223472559 + 1.682941969615793*1j; 
       2.161209223472559 - 1.682941969615793*1j, 2]

inv(mat)
-0.570919803469126 + 0i                   0.616938572560308 + 0.480412449271497i
0.616938572560308 - 0.480412449271497i    -0.570919803469126+0i
```

You can get same output in Mathematica by doing the direct computation itself without calling `Inverse`

```
foo[x11_, x12_, x21_, x22_] := 
    Module[{}, {{x22, -x12}, {-x21, x11}}/(x11*x22 - x21*x12)]
foo[2, 2.161209223472559 + 1.682941969615793 I, 
     2.161209223472559 - 1.682941969615793 I, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is an exact zero for the complex part:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And can see it match the Matlab output. Even compiled version did not resolve the issue (even though told it to run in hardware floating point)

```
cf = Compile[{{x11, _Complex},{x12, _Complex},{x21, _Complex},
        {x22,_Complex}},
   Inverse[{{x22, -x12}, {-x21, x11}}], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

cf[2, 2.161209223472559^1 + 1.682941969615793^1 I, 
 2.161209223472559^1 - 1.682941969615793^1 I, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we do break the inverse to 2 parts, and do one by 'hand' and then use `Det` only, then now the accuracy improves a little, and now it is of order `10^-17`

```
foo1[x11_, x12_, x21_, x22_] := 
 Module[{}, {{x22, -x12}, {-x21, x11}}/Det[{{x11, x12}, {x21, x22}}]]
foo1[2, 2.161209223472559 + 1.682941969615793 I, 
 2.161209223472559 - 1.682941969615793 I, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is Maple 2015 result also:

```
mat:=<<2|2.161209223472559 + 1.682941969615793*I>,
      <2.161209223472559 - 1.682941969615793*I|2>>;
LinearAlgebra[MatrixInverse](mat);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So matlab and maple, no matter how they done it internally, they done it right. Can we say that `Inverse` in mma has some defects? But I think for numerical inversion, they should be all implementing BLAS or Lapack, right? Why such a difference?

Comment: Possibly Matlab and Mathematica are getting the same result. It seems Mathematica shows one more decimal place (I don't know what the Matlab result would look like if it showed one more place), `In[68]:= Inverse[mat] // InputForm
Out[68]//InputForm=
{{-0.5709198034691264 + 6.016932509384263*^-17*I, 0.6169385725603085 + 0.4804124492714965*I}, 
{0.6169385725603084 - 0.4804124492714966*I, -0.5709198034691264 + 5.551115123125783*^-17*I}}`

Comment: i updated my post. hope you have a look