# How to implement Outer with loops

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I would like to implement a simplified version of `Outer` (`Outer[f, vec1, vec2,..]`) through a looping construct.

Here are is one thing that works, but is not quite down to the level I'd like it to be on (think, say, what is a available in C). Using `Table` one could do the following:

```
v1 = {a, b, c};
v2 = {A, B, C, D};
Table[Table[f[i, j], {j, v2}], {i, v1}] === Outer[f, v1, v2]
True
```

I know that the result should be of the form (this is correct for n vectors):

```
lsts = {v1, v2};
res = ConstantArray[0, Join[Length /@ lsts, {Length[lsts]}]]
```

A `Do` loop would look like this:

```
Do[
 Do[
  res[[j, i, 1]] = lsts[[1, j]];
  res[[j, i, 2]] = lsts[[2, i]];
  , {i, Length[lsts[[2]]]}]
 , {j, Length[lsts[[1]]]}]

res == Outer[List, lsts[[1]], lsts[[2]]]
True
```

My question is how would I generalize the do loop for n vectors?

[Mathics](https://github.com/mathics/Mathics/blob/dc87d67f43e5a6947402a8725791d15646ea16c2/mathics/builtin/tensors.py) does this via recursion. Looking at the output of a compiled outer did not give an idea either:

```
cf = Compile[{}, Outer[List, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]];
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[cf]
```

Comment: Why would you like to do this? If this is a quest for better understanding you might want to skip loops altogether and if you are trying to improve performance you ought to look elsewhere since loops are not efficient in Mathematica.

Comment: You can build your `Do`-loop code using [metaprogramming](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2335/121).  However one usually wishes to go the other direction in *Mathematica*, i.e. convert verbose loops into concise high-level abstractions such as `Outer`, therefore I echo Sascha's question: *why?*  If you explain the purpose behind this question it is likely that you will get more useful replies that if you do not.

Comment: @Sascha, I'd like to implement a Outer in C for integer packed arrays.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, while it's true that in most cases vectorization is the way to go in mathematica it's by no means always the case. For example the use of loops in `Compile` can outperform vectorized operations, esp. when the compilation target is C. Maybe this forum is not quite the right place to ask, but in a C forum people might have a hard time to understand `Outer`.

Comment: If you're going for performance in a particular situation, I would suggest amending your question with a simple example problem for benchmarking, and maybe an algorithm to beat. People go ape for questions like that around here...

Comment: I'm not clear on the goal here. Are you using Mathematica to prototype an algorithm which you will write in C, or are you after a CompiledFunction in Mathematica which you can use in place of Outer?

Comment: [My answer to "How to implement the general array broadcasting method from NumPy?" question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99553/14303) contains "C" implementation of broadcasting, which "overlaps" with `Outer`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an implementation in C, this might be quite close. Here's an example with three vectors:

```
{x1, x2, x3} = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}};

out = ConstantArray[0, {Length[x1], Length[x2], Length[x3]}];
For[i1 = 1, i1 <= Length[x1], i1++,
 For[i2 = 1, i2 <= Length[x2], i2++,
  For[i3 = 1, i3 <= Length[x3], i3++,
   out[[i1, i2, i3]] = f[x1[[i1]], x2[[i2]], x3[[i3]]]
   ]
  ]
 ]

out == Outer[f, Range[3], Range[4], Range[2]]
(* True *)
```

Here's a `List` example:

```
{x[1], x[2], x[3]} = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}};
nArgs = 3;
out = ConstantArray[
   0, {Length[x[1]], Length[x[2]], Length[x[3]], nArgs}];
For[i[1] = 1, i[1] <= Length[x[1]], i[1]++,
 For[i[2] = 1, i[2] <= Length[x[2]], i[2]++,
  For[i[3] = 1, i[3] <= Length[x[3]], i[3]++,
   For[i[0] = 1, i[0] <= nArgs, i[0]++,
    out[[i[1], i[2], i[3], i[0]]] = x[ i[0] ][[ i[ i[0] ] ]]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]

out == Outer[List, Range[3], Range[4], Range[2]]
(* True *)
```

Notice, how I switched over to *indexed* variables `x[1]`, `x[2]`, etc. to make generalization easier. `i[0]` here refers to the position of the argument.

This does indeed seem like a task for recursion, but I don't have time to go that far.